# Running mongo on elastic beanstalk and connecting to it - pros and cons?

Tags: spring, mongodb, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a 3 tier application. My question relates to the spring boot rest api middle tier and mongodb backend on aws.
I am thinking of running mongodb docker container in elastic beanstalk/single container option, for scaling the backend.

My rest api will run as docker container in a separate elastic beanstalk environment.

My understanding that elastic beanstalk will scale the dockerized mongodb service as needed.

High level architecture:

Frontend - Angular -  s3 static website hosting

Middle tier - 3 Spring boot rest services - 3 separate environemnts with single container docker scaled with elastic bean stalk.

Backend - Mongodb - Single Docker container scaled  with elastic bean stalk.

Questions:

Qn: Will this work? Will each tier scale? Will rest service be able to connect to database? How much will this cost? Will there be too much latency between the middle tier and backend?

Qn: Is this a foolhardy chase for any reason, that has some hurdle I am not seeing? My research on this approach has yielded almost nothing. Would someone discourage from even trying this? :)

Notes:

Elastic beanstalk appears to offer convenience at a slightly higher cost. I am willing to accept it, as I am just testing. Kubernetes/docker swarm appear too complex and time consuming as I need to focus on application function in the near term.

I should be able to map a volume to a physical location in aws. Guess elastic block storage or EFS. Any pros and cons or better alternatives?

I am aware that I can use thin jars for efficiency.

I have tested it with mongodb deployed on EC2. I should be able to set it up to work launch configurations and autoscaling groups. But I think it will be more expensive, and likely more work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "Single Docker container scaled with elastic bean stalk" but if you intend to launch more containers running MongoDB, the reality is a little more complicated than that.

While MongoDB does scale horizontally, when a new node is launched in a replica set topology, it:

- must be added to the replica set configuration
- needs to have the data that the other nodes already have synced onto it

There are tools that handle both of these requirements but simply bringing up another container is not enough.

Sharded clusters are even more complex because a node needs to be assigned into a shard so there are two levels of management decisions made.

> I need to focus on application function in the near term.

You may consider MongoDB Atlas which will handle all of this for you. There is a [free tier](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-42-now-available-on-the-atlas-free-tier) available.

Comment: Agreed. Managing scalable databases is a ton of work and requires a lot of knowledge to stay out of trouble. Offloading it to a platform is exactly the right move if you need to focus on your business logic.